# Primary key auto increment reset when table data dropped

Tags: sql, db2

I'm creating a table where the primary key will be an int that is auto incremented. This is for a staging table that will be deleted from every night. When the daily job reloads the table the next day, will the next primary key reset back to 1, or will it continue from previous day's top value?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an auto increment primary key column in your table the result will be  depending which delete method you use. When using the "TRUNCATE TABLE" method the auto increment seed value will be reset back to 1. When using the "DELETE FROM" method the auto increment seed will be left as it was before (eg if the auto increment field of last inserted record was 123 the next inserted record will be set to 124).

Comment: `TRUNCATE thetable RESTART IDENTITY;` will restart the sequence. Without the `RESTART IDENTITY` it will continue where it left off.

Comment: the answer suggests that truncate automatically restarts identity. so would it be possible to just delete from with restart identity, or do I HAVE to truncate and restart identity?

Comment: The answer may be platform or version-dependent. On DB2 LUW the `TRUNCATE` statement does **not** reset the identity sequences, and there is no `RESTART IDENTITY` clause. As far as I know, the same applies to DB2 z/OS.